# fwrite writing from beginning without removing

Tags: php, fwrite

I am using PHP and fwrite code, but I want every write position to start from the beginning of the file without erasing it's content. I am using this code but it is writing to the end of the file.

```
$fr = fopen("aaaa.txt", "a");
fwrite($fr, "text");
fclose($fr);
```

Answer (score 3):

So you want to write at the beginning of a file, leaving all of its current contents after the new data? You'll have to grab its existing contents first, then append it back into the file once you've overwritten with your new data.

```
$file = 'aaaa.txt';
$oldContents = file_get_contents($file);
$fr = fopen($file, 'w');
fwrite($fr, "text");
fwrite($fr, $oldContents);
fclose($fr);
```

If you want to avoid loading the original file's contents into memory in your PHP script, you might try first writing to a temp file, using a loop buffer or system calls to append the contents of your original file to the temp file, then remove the original file and rename your temp file.

Answer (score 1):

From the PHP site:

> Note:
>
> If you have opened the file in append ("a" or "a+") mode, any data you
>   write to the file will always be appended, regardless of the file
>   position

I suggest something like this (from php.net site):

```
$handle = fopen('output.txt', 'r+');

fwrite($handle, 'Really long sentence.');
rewind($handle);
fwrite($handle, 'Foo');
rewind($handle);

echo fread($handle, filesize('output.txt'));

fclose($handle);
```

Comment: Thanks for noticing the point about appending. I previously just assumed that fseek always worked.

Comment: This overwrites the file's contents from the beginning. Asker wants to retain its contents instead. The example you copied is even titled "rewind() overwriting example."

Comment: completely misread the question then. I believe the only solution is to read the file and write it back with a loop to save memory for big files using fread and fwrite

Comment: I wouldn't say that's the _only_ solution, but it might be the only way in PHP alone. That's a really hairy way of doing it, though, as you'd have to maintain several buffers to avoid clobbering existing data.

Comment: wel.. yes, we are talking about PHP here, and several buffers as in.. 2 ? one for the old files pointer (previously renamed it), one for the new file (that has the new content already in it as first fwrite).  This is a really bad way to do it if the file has multiple write at the same time it can be a mess... but in that case a semaphore can be created: `while(old_file_exists){usleep(1000);}`

Comment: Okay, I get you now. Using a temp file is fine. I thought you meant, without a temp file, writing to the front of the same file while reading from farther ahead in the same file. That's why I said it was "really hairy."

Answer (score 0):

```
$file = 'aaaa.txt';
$tmp = file_get_contents($file);
$tmp = 'text'.$tmp;
$tmp = file_put_contents($file, $tmp);
echo ($tmp != false)? 'OK': '!OK';
```

Comment: And if this is a large file? You want to put it all in memory?

Answer (score 0):

use this code :

```
$file = 'aaaa.txt';
$oldContents = file_get_contents($file);
$fr = fopen($file, 'w');
$newmsg="text".$oldContents;
fwrite($fr, $oldContents);
fclose($fr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Prefetching old content with file_get_contents and appending it after writing new content is one way to do it.
But In case, the file is being dynamically written and along the way you needed to go back to the beginning of file and add some text, then here is how:

```
$handle = fopen($FILE_PATH, 'w+');
fwrite($handle, "I am writing to a new empty file 
                and now I need to add Hello World to the beginning");
```

to prepend Hello World do the following:

```
$oldText = '';
fseek($handle, 0);
while (!feof($handle)) {
   $oldText .= fgets($handle);
}
fseek($handle, 0);
fwrite($handle, "Hello World! ");
fwrite($handle, $oldText);

fclose($handle);
```

The result would be:

> Hello World! I am writing to a new empty file 
>                       and now I need to add Hello World to the beginning

Reminder and like [Fabrizio](https://stackoverflow.com/users/583230/fabrizio) already noted:

> If you have opened the file in append ("a" or "a+") mode, any data you
>   write to the file will always be appended, regardless of the file
>   position

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
$file="name.extension";
$current = file_get_contents($file);
$user = $_POST["username"];
$pass = $_POST["password"];
file_put_contents($file,$current . "Whatever you want to add here"
```

This finds the current stuff and copy/pastes it back each time the code is ran (tried to make it as simple as possible in case other answers are a little too complicated)

Answer (score 0):

1. Open a file in w+ mode not a+ mode.
2. Get the length of text to add ($chunkLength)
3. set a file cursor to the beginning of the file
4. read $chunkLength bytes from the file
5. return the cursor to the $chunkLength * $i;
6. write $prepend
7. set $prepend a value from step 4
8. do these steps, while EOF

   ```
   $handler = fopen('1.txt', 'w+');//1
   rewind($handler);//3
   $prepend = "I would like to add this text to the beginning of this file";
   $chunkLength = strlen($prepend);//2
   $i = 0;
   do{
       $readData = fread($handler, $chunkLength);//4
       fseek($handler, $i * $chunkLength);//5
       fwrite($handler, $prepend);//6

       $prepend = $readData;//7
       $i++;
   }while ($readData);//8

   fclose($handler);
   ```

Answer (score 0):

First open the file in c+ mode which opens file or create new file if doesnot exists and points the pointer at beginning of the file. To get old content use `file_get_contents` and check if the file exists.

```
$fh = fopen($file_path, 'c+'); 

if (file_exists($file_path)) {   
    $oldContents = file_get_contents($file_path);  
    fwrite($fh,"New Content" );  
    fwrite($fh, $oldContents);   
} else {   
    fwrite($fh,"New Content");   
}   

fclose($fh);
```

Answer (score -2):

Use [fseek()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fseek.php) to set your position in the file.

```
$fr = fopen("aaaa.txt", "r+");
fseek($fr, 0); // this line will set the position to the beginning of the file
fwrite($fr, "text");
fclose($fr);
```

Comment: As noted in Fabrizio's answer, opening in "a" mode will append to the end of the file regardless of current pointer's position.

Comment: This will overwrite content of file