# Append at the beginning of the file in PHP

Tags: php

Hi I want to append a row at the beginning of the file using php.

Lets say for example the file is containing the following contnet:

```
    Hello Stack Overflow, you are really helping me a lot.
```

And now i Want to add a row on top of the repvious one like this:

```
    www.stackoverflow.com
    Hello Stack Overflow, you are really helping me a lot.
```

This is the code that I am having at the moment in a script.

```
    $fp = fopen($file, 'a+') or die("can't open file");
    $theOldData = fread($fp, filesize($file));
    fclose($fp);

    $fp = fopen($file, 'w+') or die("can't open file");
    $toBeWriteToFile = $insertNewRow.$theOldData;
    fwrite($fp, $toBeWriteToFile);
    fclose($fp);
```

I want some optimal solution for it, as I am using it in a php script. Here are some solutions i found on here:
[Need to write at beginning of file with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1760525/need-to-write-at-beginning-of-file-with-php)

which says the following to append at the beginning:

```
    <?php
    $file_data = "Stuff you want to add\n";
    $file_data .= file_get_contents('database.txt');
    file_put_contents('database.txt', $file_data);
    ?>
```

And other one here:
[Using php, how to insert text without overwriting to the beginning of a text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/103593/using-php-how-to-insert-text-without-overwriting-to-the-beginning-of-a-text-fil)

says the following:

```
    $old_content = file_get_contents($file);
    fwrite($file, $new_content."\n".$old_content);
```

So my final question is, which is the best method to use (I mean optimal) among all the above methods. Is there any better possibly than above?

Looking for your thoughts on this!!!.

Comment: From manual `If filename does not exist, the file is created. Otherwise, the existing file is overwritten, unless the FILE_APPEND flag is set.`

Comment: @Robert, My question is, which is the best method to use for this. Please read it completely. I have also mentioned your possible duplicate in the question as its already asked.

Comment: Is the file read in PHP as well? (is the resulting file being later processed for reading in PHP?)

Comment: `file_get_contents` might need to read complete file in the memory .. how to read it part by part just like 'w+'?

Comment: @ring0, I din't understood your question quite enough. I am doing read and write with php only.

Comment: I mean, the file is created and extended for a reason: how do you plan to use the file later on, ie for reading: is it read by PHP (to display in a web page for instance), or is it read in a text editor...

Comment: Here's another good resource http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6681221/fwrite-writing-from-beginning-without-removing

Comment: I am using it in page here http://uniqueminds.in/freshersjobs.php . Here I will be adding a new row at the top of the table. SO what i am doing is: `I have the website header in variable, the table file contents in a text file and the footer in a variable. Then i will put that page contents in the following fashion **myheader.textfile.footer**. So whenever I want to update the table, i will just insert a new row like I said above.`

Comment: @ksreddy file_get_contents and file_put_contents are the same funtions as fopen, fwrite, fread etc. but they are only shorter to write. That Question  makes no sense at all, you can read it in manual. `file_put_contents - This function is identical to calling fopen(), fwrite() and fclose() successively to write data to a file.`

Comment: @Robert, That is what I am talking about. May be  `file_get_contents` and `file_put_contents` are identical to what `open()`, `fwrite()` and `fclose()`. But I have asked if there's any better solution or any advantage one over the other for what I am having right now.

Comment: How come this question is marked as duplicate, when myself compared with the duplicates you provided in my question already before you said and explained the situation.

Answer (score 8):

```
function file_prepend ($string, $filename) {

  $fileContent = file_get_contents ($filename);

  file_put_contents ($filename, $string . "\n" . $fileContent);
}
```

usage :

```
file_prepend("couldn't connect to the database", 'database.logs');
```

Answer (score 1):

My personal preference when writing to a file is to use [`file_put_contents`](http://php.net/file_put_contents)

From the manual:

> This function is identical to calling fopen(), fwrite() and fclose()
>   successively to write data to a file.

Because the function automatically handles those three functions for me I do not have to remember to close the resource after I'm done with it.

Comment: Programmers... always lazy :D

Answer (score 1):

There is no really efficient way to write before the first line in a file. Both solutions mentioned in your questions create a new file from copying everything from the old one then write new data (and there is no much difference between the two methods).

If you are really after efficiency, ie avoiding the whole copy of the existing file, and you need to have the last inserted line being the first in the file, it all depends how you plan on using the file after it is created.

*three files*

Per you comment, you could create three files `header`, `content` and `footer` and output each of them in sequence ; that would avoid the copy even if `header` is created after `content`.

*work reverse in one file*

This method puts the file in memory (array).
Since you know you create the content before the header, always *write* lines in reverse order, footer, content, then header:

```
function write_reverse($lines, $file) { // $lines is an array
   for($i=count($lines)-1 ; $i>=0 ; $i--) fwrite($file, $lines[$i]);
}
```

then you call `write_reverse()` first with footer, then content and finally header. Each time you want to add something at the *beginning* of the file, just write at the end...

Then to read the file for output

```
$lines = array();
while (($line = fgets($file)) !== false) $lines[] = $line;

// then print from last one
for ($i=count($lines)-1 ; $i>=0 ; $i--) echo $lines[$i];
```

Then there is another consideration: could you avoid using files at all - eg via [PHP APC](http://php.net/manual/en/book.apc.php)

Comment: nice thought. But if I use this `function write_reverse($lines, $file) { // $lines is an array
   for($i=count($lines)-1 ; $i>=0 ; $i--) fwrite($file, $lines[$i]);
}` this will eat away the time as its repeating for each and every line of the file as opposed to current solution writing whole data at a time to the file.

Comment: It depends on how you create the file initially (this is not part of the question). The `write_reverse` is done only once when file is created, or extended. Sure, line by line in interpreted PHP is a bit slower than a unique operation - but using `write_reverse` you don't copy the whole file when adding something like a header... only the new lines. This will make a difference especially if the file is big.

Answer (score 1):

You mean prepending. I suggest you read the line and replace it with next line without losing data.

```
<?php

$dataToBeAdded = "www.stackoverflow.com";
$file = "database.txt"; 

$handle = fopen($file, "r+");

$final_length = filesize($file) + strlen($dataToBeAdded );

$existingData = fread($handle, strlen($dataToBeAdded ));

rewind($handle);

$i = 1;

while (ftell($handle) < $final_length) 
{

  fwrite($handle, $dataToBeAdded );

  $dataToBeAdded  = $existingData ;

  $existingData  = fread($handle, strlen($dataToBeAdded ));

  fseek($handle, $i * strlen($dataToBeAdded ));

  $i++;
}
?>
```