# PHP fwrite - how to insert new lines in the middle of the file instead of overwritting them

Tags: php, fwrite, overwrite

Hi there fellow coders,

I have a strange issue with fwrite, and i am afraid i cannot handle it.

I am trying to "insert" an html element in the middle of a '.tpl' file, but I just cannot make it work right.

here is my code:

```
$config = './menu.tpl';
$file=fopen($config,"r+") or exit("Unable to open file!");
$insertPos=0;        // used as index
while (!feof($file)) {
    $line=fgets($file);
    if (strpos($line, '<div id="target">the point of insertion</div>')!==false) {
        $insertPos=ftell($file);
    }
}

fseek($file,$insertPos);
fwrite($file, 'new content');
fclose($file);
```

you see, the menu.tpl is a big file with lots of content.

when the fwrite starts appending content, 
it overwrites the lines below, instead of adding new lines.

I have tried many new-line 'commands', like `\n`,  `\r` and `PHP_EOL`, in many combinations (before the content, after, separated the content in segments)
but the outcome is always the same:

content is "pasted" above the existing, resulting in a broken outcome.

My logic dictates that there must be a "ADD MORE SPACE FOR PASTED CONTENT" command for fwrite, but I cannot find one.

Thanks in advance for any insights :)

Panos

Comment: Look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6681221/fwrite-writing-from-beginning-without-removing

Comment: Thanks wandam, but I have seen all these options.
I wish to avoid the file splitting, I was hoping to find a more elegant solution :)